# I am incrementing a program counter in a CPU code and it stalls at six and its multiples for several cycles before it continues

Tags: binary, vhdl, intel-fpga

I am coding a 16-bit CPU for a school project and I've run into an issue that has dumbfounded me. The first three steps of my clock cycle are naturally to increment the program counter and load a new instruction into the instruction register. So the problem; the value in the program counter increments as expected but stalls at 6 for several cycles then picks up again and stalls at 12 for several more, again at 18 and then 24, this is as far as I've let it run, I assume it'll persist at succeeding multiples of six. I dunno if it is something to do with the way VHDL treats signed values, I edited the ALU code to achieve this by adding one to the Program Counter value instead of incrementing but there was no change, I changed the ALUs representation of the values to unsigned but that didn't help and I honestly cannot see why it would. My code is as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity CPU_1 is
    port( prim_clk : in std_logic;
            achtung : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) ;
            HEX0, HEX1, HEX2 : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end CPU_1;

Architecture behaviour of Nandos is
    signal sys_clk, clk, cu_s, cu_e: std_logic;
    signal step : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    signal acc_ena, acc_set, pc_set, pc_ena: std_logic := 'Z';
    signal data_bus, alu_acc : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);--M_addr_bus, 
             
    component Clock 
    port( clk : in std_logic; --50 MHz
            clk_s : out std_logic;--set data clk
            clk_e : out std_logic);--enable data(on bus) clk
    end component;
    component Control_Unit
    port( sys_clk, clk_s, clk_e : in std_logic;
            acc_ena, acc_set, pc_set, pc_ena: out std_logic;
            stepp     : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0));      
    end component;
    component program_Counter
    port( clk: in std_logic;
            set, en : in std_logic;
            pc_in : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);   
            pc_out : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));    
    end component;  
    component ALU 
    port( clk: in std_logic;
            d1 : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            d3 : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));            
    end component;
    component accumulator
    port( clk: in std_logic;
            frm_ALU: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            acc_set, acc_ena : in std_logic;
            to_bus : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));    
    end component;  
    
begin
    HEX2(5 downto 0) <= step;--serves to demonstrate on the board that it is running
    achtung <= data_bus;--debug what is on the bus
    clk0 : Clock port map(prim_clk, cu_s, cu_e);
    cu0  : Control_Unit port map(prim_clk, cu_s, cu_e, acc_ena, acc_set, pc_set, pc_ena, step);
    p_c  : program_Counter port map(prim_clk, pc_set, pc_ena, data_bus, data_bus);
    alu0 : ALU port map(prim_clk, data_bus, alu_acc);
    acc  : accumulator port map(prim_clk, alu_acc, acc_set, acc_ena, data_bus);                     
end behaviour;
```

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Control_Unit is
    port( sys_clk, clk_s, clk_e : in std_logic;
            acc_ena, acc_set, pc_set, pc_ena: out std_logic;
            stepp     : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0));  --just to ko
end Control_Unit;

architecture behaviour of Control_Unit is
    signal step : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    component Stepper 
    port( clk : in std_logic;
            step : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0));
    end component;
begin   
    stpr  : Stepper port map(sys_clk, step);
    stepp <= step;
    process(sys_clk, step)      
        begin
        if rising_edge(sys_clk) then
            if step(0) = '1' then
                case clk_s is
                when '1' =>
                    acc_set <= '1';
                when '0' =>
                    acc_set <= '0';
                end case;
                case clk_e is
                when '1' =>
                    pc_ena <= '1';
                when '0' =>
                    pc_ena <= '0';
                end case;
            elsif step(1) = '1' then
                case clk_s is
                when '1' =>
                    null;
                when '0' =>
                    null;
                end case;
                case clk_e is
                when '1' =>
                    null;
                when '0' =>
                    null;           
                end case;
            elsif step(2) = '1' then
                case clk_s is
                when '1' =>
                    pc_set <= '1';
                when '0' =>
                    pc_set <= '0';
                end case;
                case clk_e is
                when '1' =>
                    acc_ena <= '1';
                when '0' =>
                    acc_ena <= '0';
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;    
end behaviour;
```

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY ALU IS
    port( clk: in std_logic;
            d1: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            d3 : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));    
END ALU;

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF ALU IS
    signal Zsig: signed(15 downto 0);
begin   
    process(clk, d1)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            Zsig <= signed(d1) + 1;
        end if;
end process;  
    d3 <= std_logic_vector(signed(Zsig));   
end behaviour;
```

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Clock is
    port( clk :in std_logic; 
            clk_s : out std_logic;
            clk_e : out std_logic);
end Clock;
--slowing down the clock so I can track data flow. 
architecture Behavioral of Clock is
    signal count: integer := 1;
    signal clock_1: std_logic := '1';
    signal clock_2: std_logic := '0';
begin
    process(clk)
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            count <= count + 1;
            if count = 12500000 then  --10
                clock_1 <= not clock_1; 
                count <= 1;                             
            elsif count = 5000000 then--4
                clock_2 <= not clock_2;
            end if;         
        end if;     
        end process;    
        clk_e <= clock_1 or clock_2;
        clk_s <= clock_1 and clock_2;
end Behavioral;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity stepper is
    port (clk : in std_logic;
            step: out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0));
end stepper;

architecture behav of stepper is
    signal count : integer := 0;
begin
    Process(clk)
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
       count <= count+1;
        if count = 0 then  --0
            step <= "000001";
        elsif count = 23750000 then  --19
            step <= "000010";
        elsif count = 48750000 then  --39
            step <= "000100";
        elsif count = 73750000 then  --59
            step <= "001000";
        elsif count = 98750000 then  --79
            step <= "010000";
        elsif count = 123750000 then --99 
            step <= "100000";
        elsif count = 148750000 then --119
            count <= 0;
        end if;
    end if;
    end Process;
end behav;

library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity program_Counter is
    port( clk: in std_logic;
            set, en : in std_logic;
            pc_in : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);   
            pc_out : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));    
    end program_Counter;
    
Architecture behaviour of program_Counter is
    signal RAM : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk, RAM, set, en)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if set = '1' then
                RAM <= pc_in;
            elsif en = '1' then
                pc_out <= RAM;
            else
                pc_out <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;        
end behaviour;  

library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity accumulator is
    port( clk: in std_logic;
            frm_ALU: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            acc_set, acc_ena : in std_logic;
            to_bus : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));    
    end accumulator;
    
Architecture behaviour of accumulator is    
    signal RAM : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 
begin
    process(clk, acc_set, acc_ena, RAM)
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if  acc_set = '1' then
                RAM <= frm_ALU;
            elsif acc_ena = '1' then    
                to_bus <= RAM;  
            else 
                to_bus <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end behaviour;
```

Sorry for what must be riddled with coding taboos. I feel I should point out that when I originally wrote the code it ran fine with an ADD instruction, I changed it to increment for simplification and didn't run into any problems that I can remember. Several additions later I start getting this error so I strip everything else down to bare bones, removing registers and such but here the error still is.

I use the Quartus II 13.0 software to code and an Altera DE2 EP2C35F672C6 to run the code. Thank you.

Comment: Did you write a testbench and simulate? With one you can debug what's happening.

Comment: No I have not, I have only a general idea of what a testbench is. Now is a good a time as any to fix that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, after preloading the program counter with the value for 5 and not immediately running into the error when it tried to increment 6 to 7 but instead at 11 it became clear that the logic was not the culprit. The steppers first stage lasts a little shorter than the others(1250000 ticks to be exact) and it desyncs after 6 cycles, after a few more cycles it syncs up again, runs correctly and desyncs again after 6 more. This has been resolved and the counter now increments endlessly, as desired.